# How to add values in array in php?

Tags: php, arrays

I have two variables: `$report1` and `$report2`

```
 function overallStats($startdate, $enddate) {
          $reports1 = $analytic_report->reports->query('contentOwner==first',
          $startdate, $enddate, 'views,earnings', array(
          'dimensions' => 'day',
          'filters' => 'claimedStatus==claimed',
          'sort' => 'day'
          ));
          $reports2 = $analytic_report->reports->query('contentOwner==second',
          $startdate, $enddate, 'views,earnings', array(
          'dimensions' => 'day',
          'filters' => 'claimedStatus==claimed',
          'sort' => 'day'
          ));
          $reports =  array_merge($reports1, $reports2);
    }

    function second(){
        $overallrawstats = $this->overallStats(date('Y-m-d', strtotime('9 days ago')), date('Y-m-d', strtotime('yesterday')));
        if (!empty($overallrawstats)) {
            $overallstats = array();
            foreach($overallrawstats as $p=>$o) {
              $overallstats[] = array(
              recorddate => $o[0],
              views => $o[1],
              revenue => $o[2]
              );
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to get a third array which merged all the values of these two array, But when I get third merged array in it views and earnings should be add of these two array. How can I get it?

Comment: Can you show structure of those two arrays and what you have tried so far to join them?

Comment: Your question is highly unclear. Please be specific on what array you want as an output. If possible, please mention a demo output which you require.

Comment: check edit part.. currently i am using array_merge. Its giving me only $reports2's view and earning . But i want sum of them

Answer (score 0):

assuming both arrays are equally of length:

```
$report3 = array();
foreach ($report1 as $index => $value) {
    array_push($report3, (int) $value + (int) $report2[$index]);
}
```